# check if all names in df1 appear for each ID in df2

Tags: r

I have two dfs like this:

df1

```
name <- c("Ted","Bill","James","Randy","Mark","Jimmy","Eric","Allen")
team <- c("Hawks","Tigers","Bears","Tigers","Lions","Bears","Hawks","Lions")
df1 <- data.frame(name,team)
```

df2

```
 name <- c("Ted","Bill","Mark","Jimmy","Eric","James","Allen","Randy","Bill","James","Mark")
 team <- c("Hawks","Tigers","Lions","Bears","Hawks","Bears","Lions","Tigers","Tigers","Bears","Lions")
 game_id <- c("21","23","28","21","21","21","29","22","22","32","42")
 df2 <- data.frame(name,team,game_id)
```

I want to mark the game_ids in df2 with `NA` if the game_id does not have ALL of the names for its respective team in df1. In the sample data I provided, for example, game_id 32 in the row containing "James" and "Bears" would be one of the game_ids marked `NA` because "Jimmy" isn't represented for game_id 32 in df2. We know that Jimmy must be represented because he appears in a row in df1 with "Bears" indicated for his team.

My desired output for my sample data would look like this:

df3

```
name <- c("Ted","Bill","Mark","Jimmy","Eric","James","Allen","Randy","Bill","James","Mark")
team <- c("Hawks","Tigers","Lions","Bears","Hawks","Bears","Lions","Tigers","Tigers","Bears","Lions")
game_id <- c("21",NA,NA,"21","21","21",NA,"22","22",NA,NA)
df3 <- data.frame(name,team,game_id)
```

I think the solution starts by spreading df1 (after adding a unique ID column), like this:

```
df1$row_index <- seq.int(nrow(df1))
df1 <- spread(df1,team,name)
```

But I get stuck after that point. What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this via an "anti-join" against all the correct combinations of team/name:

```
badgames <- df1 %>%
  full_join(distinct(select(df2, game_id, team)), by="team") %>%
  anti_join(df2, by=c("team", "game_id", "name")) %>%
  select(game_id,team) %>%
  mutate(hit = 1)

df2 %>%
  left_join(badgames, by=c("game_id","team")) %>%
  mutate(game_id = replace(game_id, hit==1, NA), hit = NULL)
```

The same logic works in `data.table` keyed joins, where you can specify an anti-join by putting `!` in front of the joined table. You can also do the update all in the same step using `:=` instead of creating an intermediary dataset:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
df2[
  df1[unique(df2[, .(game_id,team)]), on=.(team)][
    !df2, on=.(game_id, team, name)], on=.(game_id,team),
    game_id := NA
  ]
```

Both resulting in:

```
#    name   team game_id
#1    Ted  Hawks      21
#2   Bill Tigers    <NA>
#3   Mark  Lions    <NA>
#4  Jimmy  Bears      21
#5   Eric  Hawks      21
#6  James  Bears      21
#7  Allen  Lions    <NA>
#8  Randy Tigers      22
#9   Bill Tigers      22
#10 James  Bears    <NA>
#11  Mark  Lions    <NA>
```

Comment: This code replaces game_id with `NA` based only on game_id, not game_id and team criteria. If we change Eric/Hawks game_id to 50, we have a situation where game_id 21 is invalid for Hawks, but valid for Bears. My modification is this, but is there a better way to do it? `badgames <- df1 %>%
  full_join(distinct(select(df2, game_id, team)), by="team") %>%
  anti_join(df2, by=c("team", "game_id", "name")) %>%
  mutate(gameidteam = paste0(game_id,team))

df2$gameidteam <- paste0(game_id,team)
df2 <- mutate(df2, game_id = replace(game_id, gameidteam %in% badgames$gameidteam, NA) )`

Comment: Also, can you explain why the following code, which avoids having to create another column with pasted values, does not work? This ifelse statement appears to only consider the code on the left side of the `&` `df2$game_id <- apply(df2,1,function(x) ifelse((x[which(names(x)=="game_id")] %in% badgames$game_id) & (x[which(names(x)=="team")] %in% badgames$team),NA,x[which(names(x)=="game_id")]))`

Comment: @orangeman51 - I've updated the answer to account for the new criteria. I just join back on multiple variables and use a flag to update the selected rows. In `data.table` I just had to add an extra variable for the join - it should still work the same.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way using counts. We're comparing the number of players on each team in `df1` to the number of players at each game for each team in `df2`. This could be tripped up if `df1` was an incomplete list of players, e.g. if the Lions had two players in `df1` and two totally different players played for them in a game in `df2`, but if I understand the setting that shouldn't be the case.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- tibble(
  name = c("Ted","Bill","James","Randy","Mark","Jimmy","Eric","Allen"),
  team = c("Hawks","Tigers","Bears","Tigers","Lions","Bears","Hawks","Lions")
)
df2 <- tibble(
  name = c("Ted","Bill","Mark","Jimmy","Eric","James","Allen","Randy","Bill","James","Mark"),
  team = c("Hawks","Tigers","Lions","Bears","Hawks","Bears","Lions","Tigers","Tigers","Bears","Lions"),
  game_id = c("21","23","28","21","21","21","29","22","22","32","42")
)

df2 %>%
  add_count(team, game_id) %>%
  left_join(add_count(df1, team), by = c("name", "team")) %>%
  mutate(game_id = ifelse(n.x == n.y, game_id, NA)) %>%
  select(name:game_id)
#> # A tibble: 11 x 3
#>    name  team   game_id
#>    <chr> <chr>  <chr>  
#>  1 Ted   Hawks  21     
#>  2 Bill  Tigers <NA>   
#>  3 Mark  Lions  <NA>   
#>  4 Jimmy Bears  21     
#>  5 Eric  Hawks  21     
#>  6 James Bears  21     
#>  7 Allen Lions  <NA>   
#>  8 Randy Tigers 22     
#>  9 Bill  Tigers 22     
#> 10 James Bears  <NA>   
#> 11 Mark  Lions  <NA>
```

Created on 2018-04-10 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

Using `sqldf` you can skip the annoying `NA` replacements.

```
library(dplyr)
library(sqldf)
dfx <- inner_join(count(df2,game_id,team),count(df1,team))
sqldf("SELECT name, team, dfx.game_id from df2 natural left join dfx")

# or finish the dplyr chain with:
# %>% right_join(df2) %>% mutate(game_id = `is.na<-`(game_id,is.na(n))) %>% select(-n)

#        name   team game_id
#    1    Ted  Hawks      21
#    2   Bill Tigers    <NA>
#    3   Mark  Lions    <NA>
#    4  Jimmy  Bears      21
#    5   Eric  Hawks      21
#    6  James  Bears      21
#    7  Allen  Lions    <NA>
#    8  Randy Tigers      22
#    9   Bill Tigers      22
#   10  James  Bears    <NA>
#   11   Mark  Lions    <NA>
```

`data.table` has this feature as well:

```
setDT(df1)  
setDT(df2)
dfx <- df2[,.N, by=c("team","game_id")][df1[,.N, by=team],on=c("team","N")]
dfx[df2,.(name,team,game_id=x.game_id),on=c("team","game_id")]
#      name   team game_id
#  1:   Ted  Hawks      21
#  2:  Bill Tigers      NA
#  3:  Mark  Lions      NA
#  4: Jimmy  Bears      21
#  5:  Eric  Hawks      21
#  6: James  Bears      21
#  7: Allen  Lions      NA
#  8: Randy Tigers      22
#  9:  Bill Tigers      22
# 10: James  Bears      NA
# 11:  Mark  Lions      NA
```

And the base version for completeness, notice that one can merge `tables` without converting them to `data.frame` first:

```
dfx <- merge(table(df2[-1]),table(df1[-1],dnn=names(df1[-1])))
df3 <- merge(df2,dfx,all.x=T)
is.na(df3$game_id) <- is.na(df3$n)
df3 <- df3[-4]
#      team game_id  name
# 1   Bears      21 Jimmy
# 2   Bears      21 James
# 3   Bears    <NA> James
# 4   Hawks      21   Ted
# 5   Hawks      21  Eric
# 6   Lions    <NA>  Mark
# 7   Lions    <NA> Allen
# 8   Lions    <NA>  Mark
# 9  Tigers      22 Randy
# 10 Tigers      22  Bill
# 11 Tigers    <NA>  Bill
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
how_many_players <- aggregate(name ~ team, data = df1, function(x) length(unique(x)))
names(how_many_players)[2] <- "total_players"

num_played <- aggregate(name ~ game_id + team, data = df2, function(x) length(unique(x)))
names(num_played)[3] <- "num_played"

check <- merge(how_many_players, num_played)
full_games <- check[check$total_players == check$num_played, "game_id"]

df3 <- df2
df3$game_id[!df3$game_id %in% full_games] <- NA
df3
# name   team game_id
# 1    Ted  Hawks      21
# 2   Bill Tigers    <NA>
# 3   Mark  Lions    <NA>
# 4  Jimmy  Bears      21
# 5   Eric  Hawks      21
# 6  James  Bears      21
# 7  Allen  Lions    <NA>
# 8  Randy Tigers      22
# 9   Bill Tigers      22
# 10 James  Bears    <NA>
# 11  Mark  Lions    <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

the other solutions uses counting the number of players, which may not catch exactly the scenario you are looking at when the same number of players, but a different set of players are playing.

Hence, if you want to be specific about the players that are playing, you may want to concatenate all the players names in a sorted fashion and compare them.

```
name <- c("Ted","Bill","James","Randy","Mark","Jimmy","Eric","Allen")
team <- c("Hawks","Tigers","Bears","Tigers","Lions","Bears","Hawks","Lions")
df1 <- data.frame(name,team)

name <- c("Ted","Bill","Mark","Jimmy","Eric","James","Allen","Randy","Bill","James","Mark")
team <- c("Hawks","Tigers","Lions","Bears","Hawks","Bears","Lions","Tigers","Tigers","Bears","Lions")
game_id <- c("21","23","28","21","21","21","29","22","22","32","42")
# Note the game_id needs to be a string, otherwise the NAs may be improperly captured
df2 <- data.frame(name,team,game_id, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Concatenate all players names by group in df1
df1.all.members <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(team) %>% 
  arrange(name) %>% 
  summarise(all_players = paste0(name, collapse = "_"))

# Perform the same concatenation in df2
df2.all.members <- df2 %>% 
  group_by(team, game_id) %>% 
  arrange(name) %>% 
  mutate(all_players2 = paste0(name, collapse = "_")) %>%
  # Left join with the new df1
  left_join(df1.all.members, by = "team") %>%
  ungroup %>%
  # Compare if all names are the same
  mutate(game_id = ifelse(all_players2 == all_players, game_id, NA)) %>%
  # Select required fields
  select(name, team, game_id)

# # A tibble: 11 x 3
# name   team game_id
# <chr>  <chr>   <chr>
# 1 Allen  Lions    <NA>
# 2  Bill Tigers    <NA>
# 3  Bill Tigers      22
# 4  Eric  Hawks      21
# 5 James  Bears      21
# 6 James  Bears    <NA>
# 7 Jimmy  Bears      21
# 8  Mark  Lions    <NA>
# 9  Mark  Lions    <NA>
# 10 Randy Tigers      22
# 11   Ted  Hawks      21
```